# Conversion of DateTime into milliseconds

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, milliseconds, datetime-conversion

I want to convert **Date+Time** into **milliseconds**. i am using this code to convert them.

```
final TimePicker time = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
final DatePicker date = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(),
                            date.getDayOfMonth(), time.getCurrentHour(),
                            time.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
final long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

but it does't give me the correct value. for example if i want to convert this "**Sep 23 2000 02:45 AM**"
it gives me this value "**96965900504**". but this value is not like that as in these sites

http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/

http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go1=true&m=09&d=23&y=2000&hours=02&min=45&sec=0&Submit=++++++Convert+to+timestamp+++++&offset=-5

then i try to us `time.getCurrentHour() + 5` because of my current location is **GMT+5** but it does't gives me correct result. How can i get the correct value of date+time into milliseconds???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok its done
I just add TimeZone to this code

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:00");
calendar.setTimeZone(timezone);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set values directly into the Calendar you will get correct value:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2000, 8, 23, 2, 45, 0);

System.out.println("TimeInMillis:" + c.getTimeInMillis());

Date e = new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("Date:" + e);
```

result will be:

```
TimeInMillis:969666300102
Date:Sat Sep 23 02:45:00 AST 2000
```

So make sure the `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` returns correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      Date date = calendar.getTime();
      TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("your timezone");

      SimpleDateFormat formatter = 
             (SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
             DateFormat.LONG, Locale.getDefault());

      formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
      formatter.applyPattern("your pattern");
      formatter.parse("yourdate");
```